# SQL BULK INSERT zero seconds in datetime column from .csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, datetime, bulkinsert

I have a number of .csv files generated by production machines. I use BULK INSERT to load them to various tables in our MSSQL server with no errors. I recently noticed that all the tables I've used BULK INSERT to transfer the data have their datetime column with correct date and time (hours and minutes), however the seconds are zero for all records.

The column datatype is DATETIME.

Why are the seconds zeroed out on the datetimes?

Sample Data:

```
TESTBULKINSERT,TESTBULKINSERT,2017-03-10 06:01:16,,,,Z1860_1,1,0,PASSED,NA,NA,NA,0
```

BULK INSERT Command:

```
BULK INSERT Test.dbo.vICT_DATA FROM '\\server\CSV\testfile.csv'  With ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', FIRSTROW = 2, MAXERRORS = 0, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
```

Result:

```
PARTTYPE    SN  TDATE   JOBNO   BADGE   TESTMODE    TESTERID    NESTID  PASS_FAIL   FAILCODE    FAIL_DESC   FIRST_FAIL_VAL  UNITS   LNUM    ID
TESTBULKINSERT  TESTBULKINSERT  2017-03-10 06:01:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    Z1860_1 1   0   PASSED  NA  NA  NA,0    NULL    306244
```

Comment: try adding  DATAFILETYPE = 'char'

Comment: Same result using DATAFILETYPE = 'CHAR'  I've just tried added CODEPAGE = 'ACP' with the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using `SMALLDATETIME` somewhere?

Comment: That's what I thought the problem was initially, but I'm still having the problem after updating the table to DATETIME.

Comment: I test using SQL 2016 express and I have my seconds intact. What SQL version do you have?

Comment: I am using SQL Server Standard 2014 SP2.  Server Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Updated to SQL Server Standard 2014 SP2 CU4.  I noticed the VIEW through which I am inserting (forgot about the view) had it's datatype set to `SMALLDATETIME`.  This is probably where the seconds are getting truncated (rounded off).  I've updated this, so I will see tomorrow if the seconds are intact.

Comment: Seconds are now intact, looks like @Danny_ds was right, missed the `SMALLDATETIME` in the view.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting `DATETIME` with seconds through a VIEW, the VIEW should also have the datatype set to `DATETIME`.  Using `SMALLDATETIME` in the VIEW will cause the seconds to round to the nearest minutes.